# Rasterio grayscale .tif image is empty

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm facing an issue when opening a .tif using rasterio using the code below.

```
fp = 'image.tif'
image = rasterio.open(fp)
print(image.read())
```

When printing the content of the image, I get this

```
[[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]]
```

I verified all values and they are all `0`. However, when dragging the image in QGIS, I can view it and confirm that the image contains values ranging from 101 to 122.

[QGIS image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Btid.png)

Any idea on how to read the image and get these 101 to 122 values as a numpy array ?

[Here's a link to the image in question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fOVVBOPkiFkjapUVLIrL0pV2lr8e2d8j/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share the TIFF - use Dropbox or Google Drive maybe.

Comment: @MarkSetchell added a shareable link at the end of the description.

Comment: Your file seems to be as you describe it, so there's either something wrong with your rasterio installation or something wrong with your analysis. For the former, try reinstalling rasterio, or using `tifffile` on PYPI to read it, or `vips`. For the later, try checking `np.mean(image)` and `image.max()`.

Comment: It works with `tifffile`, but I need functions from `rasterio`. Image seems to be of dtype 'uint8', I'll see if I can research how to open that in `rasterio`.